# Прототипы(Наследование) JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Столкнулся с таким кодом на сайте https://learn.javascript.ru/ в тестах.

```js
function MyArray() { }
MyArray.prototype = [];

let arr = new MyArray();
arr.push(1, 2, 3);
alert(arr.length);
```

Можете пожалуйста объяснить, что происходит в этом коде? И каким образом к переменной arr можно применить метод массива push?

Comment: все, в какой-то степени, завязано на прототипах...в функции это массив

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У объектов есть внутреннее свойство `[[prototype]]`

У функций есть свойство `prototype` (не путать одно с другим)

Когда функцию вызывают через `new`, она создает объект, у которого (*при условии, что `prototype` функции - тоже объект*) свойство `[[prototype]]` (в консоли браузера отображается как `__proto__` **) будет ссылаться на `prototype` функции-конструктора.

** при этом у самого объекта нет такого свойства, это геттер, унаследованный от Object.prototype: [__proto__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

---

Каждый раз, когда у объекта запрашивают свойство / метод:

- JS сперва проверяет его наличие в самом объекте. Если не нашлось,
- По ссылке `[[prototype]]` ищет его в `prototype` функции-конструктора. Если и там не найдется,
- `prototype` функции - тоже объект, у него тоже есть `[[prototype]]` - посмотрит там. Так по "цепочке" идет вверх, пока не найдет свойство, или пока не закончится "лесенка" из `[[prototype]]`.

```js
function MyArray() {}
MyArray.prototype = [];

let arr = new MyArray();

console.log( arr ); // {} есть push? Нет. ► arr.__proto__
console.log( arr.__proto__ === MyArray.prototype ); // true

console.log( MyArray.prototype ); // [] есть push? Нет. ► MyArray.prototype.__proto__
console.log( MyArray.prototype.__proto__ === Array.prototype ); // true

console.log( arr.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("push") ); // true
console.log( arr.__proto__.__proto__ === Array.prototype ); // true
// Метод берется отсюда

arr.push(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr.length); // 3
console.log(MyArray.prototype.length); // 0

console.log( arr );
console.log( arr.hasOwnProperty("length") ); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
.as-console-wrapper code { white-space: nowrap; }
```

`length` сперва берется из `MyArray.prototype`, но дальше записывается и продолжает увеличивается у объекта `arr`.

* `MyArray.prototype = [];` — это короткая запись `MyArray.prototype = new Array();`

---

> И каким образом к переменной arr можно применить метод массива push?

Внутреннее устройство push не знаю, можно предположить, что ему всё равно, это массив, объект или кто. Если нашлось свойство `length`, добавляет переданное значение под индексом length и увеличивает length на один.

```js
let test_1 = {
  "0": 0,
  "1": 1,
  length: 0
};

Array.prototype.push.call(test_1, "bubu");

console.log(test_1); // Оппа, { "0": "bubu", "1": 1, "length": 1 }

let test_2 = {};
Array.prototype.push.call(test_1, "bubu");

console.log(test_2); // {} — нет length, не сработал.
```

Comment: у объекта **нет** внутреннего свойства `__proto__`

Comment: что-то не до конца заменил

Comment: @Grundy О_о и правда, спасибо) Да, думал как-бы это всё оформить, чтобы не превратить в кашу... `[[prototype]]`, `prototype`, `__proto__`, `getPrototypeOf` - хорошая такая путанница для новичка)

Answer (score 0):

Идея прототипов проста. Если метода или свойства нет у класса он ищет его у прототипа.

В вашем случае создаётся объект класса MyArray у которого не своего push, a прототип у него array посмотрите способы создания массивов. И у array уже есть метод push.

Сложность небольшая появляется когда вы создадите 2 объекта и вызовите push у каждого и посмотрите на результат.

Comment: _создадите 2 объекта и вызовите push у каждого и посмотрите на результат_ - создал и посмотрел, все работает как и ожидалось. О каких сложностях шла речь?